# Using Math.round in javascript adds weird number of 0s at the end

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding, digits, decimal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

I'm using Math.round to round the number and for some reason it adds weird number of 0s at the end which should not be there. Here is my code:

```
return Math.round($digit * 1000) / 1000;
```

i want numbers to have 3 decimal points

example:

```
  Math.round(29.469 * 1000) / 1000 = returns this value: 29.469000000000023
```

cant seem to figure out why.
is there a different way of rounding decimals to certain decimal point? i need 3 decimal points. Or maybe trim everything after third decimal digit? That would be perfect take the returned number and trim everything after third decimal.

Comment: To prevent devision errors, you could convert to a string and then taking a substring.

Comment: how do i trim everything after third decimal in a string

Comment: In what browser does `Math.round(29.469)` return 29.469000000000023?

Comment: its not a duplicate because they are discussing the comparisson and i dont need comparisson i need to display that value

Comment: `Math.round(29.469)` gives me 29 in Chrome.

Comment: @Giorgi. Using `chrome` and getting **29**

Comment: The closest representable IEEE `double` to 29.469 is 29.46900000000000119371179607696831226348876953125.

Comment: Math.round(29.469) should have been Math.round(29.469 * 1000)/1000 thats when it returns long number

Comment: Even so, in Chrome that returns 29.469.

Comment: why does it return long number in mine :(

Comment: I can't reproduce this - http://jsfiddle.net/daK3v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourVariable.toFixed(3);
```

Will give you what you want.

[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: toFixed is not well implemented in all browsers so im trying to avoid to use it

Comment: @Giorgi. From what I've seen,  it's well supported in all major browsers.