# different value for Math.round() in c# and Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

**C#**

```
homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualDebtService=20;
homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualLeaseExpense=50;
homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.PPR=100;


decimal DebtAndLeaseToPPRRatio = Convert.ToDecimal((homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualDebtService + homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualLeaseExpense) / homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.PPR);
```

I  Calculated the values for like  above formula . The  calculated values is

```
0.35
```

I want a digit values. So i use math.round()

```
Int finalvalue=Convert.ToInt32( Math.Round(DebtAndLeaseToPPRRatio));
```

Now That `FinalValue is 0` //It's good

**Javascript**

Now I used the same formula with same values in a `javascript` for see this below code

```
 $("#DebtAndLeaseToPPRRatio").text(Math.round(((AnnualDebtService + AnnualLeaseExpense) / PPR).toFixed(1)) + "%");
```

But Now it's display result is `1` .

When i used the same formula  Why the c# is display `0`? and `Javascript` is return `1`  ?

Comment: Check you variables in javascript, as if you do just Math.round(0.35) in javascript it will give you 0

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** Generally speaking Math.round in c# and javascript is doing the same thing. However there are several nuances. For .net details go to Jon Skeet answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c), for some of javascript issues you can find reference on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918761/using-math-round-in-javascript-adds-weird-number-of-0s-at-the-end) SO answer.

Before you go any further I would suggest you read carefully about three operations on float point numbers round, floor and ceiling.

Here is starting poing for .net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx

And one for javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

If you do simple test of Math.round(x) for the following numbers 0.1 0.5 .07 0.9, you will get the same result in both javascript and .net

Take into account that in some browsers javascript can give you "funky" results with big numbers

Check this answer [Using Math.round in javascript adds weird number of 0s at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12918761/using-math-round-in-javascript-adds-weird-number-of-0s-at-the-end)

Also, just for purpose of learning, read about bankers rounding here [Why does Math.Round(2.5) return 2 instead of 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977796/why-does-math-round2-5-return-2-instead-of-3-in-c)

Comment: If you do simple test of Math.round(x) for the following numbers 0.1 0.5 .07 0.9, you will get the same result in both javascript and .net . 


**No. I could not got same answer**.It's return difference values !

Comment: `Math.round` for `0.5` will not get you the same results, give it a try.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov read first and last links please, there is that information.

Comment: @vittore I think the OP's calculations are a bit off.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is elsewhere:

If we go with the values that you provided in your question:

```
homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualDebtService=20;
homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualLeaseExpense=50;
homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.PPR=100;

decimal DebtAndLeaseToPPRRatio =
    Convert.ToDecimal((homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualDebtService +
                       homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.AnnualLeaseExpense)/
                       homeModel.FinancialComplianceModelList.PPR);
```

Assuming that at least on of the variables involved in the calculation is a decimal `DebtAndLeaseToPPRRatio` is now `0.7` (otherwise if you're calculating `int`s you'd get `0`). Because `(20.0 + 50.0) / 100 = 0.7`, however *note that* `(20 + 50) / 100 = 0`.

Not sure where you're getting `0.35`. Also `Math.Round(0.35)` (C#) and `Math.round(0.35)` (JavaScript) would get you `0`. The difference is when you do `Math.Round(0.5)` (C#) -> `0.0` where `Math.round(0.5)` (JavaScript) -> `1`.

I'm testing your code in both languages (with the values provided) and I'm getting `1` in each case.

Comment: Where i use the Math.floor() /in c# or In javascript ?

Comment: That is obviously wrong answer. floor and round two completely different operations.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov check this three links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.floor.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling.aspx

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov Obvious difference would be for value 0.7 for instance. `round` would round it to 1 and that is what you are expecting from round. floor would make it 0. and topic starter will file another question here, why 0.7 is not being rounded to 1.

Comment: @vittore yes, you're right, however if he's asking how to round down, math.floor() would be correct. Anyway, I think the problem is in his calculation (you can see my edit), I just didn't notice it.